# Dissecting java Class file in haskell

Tags: haskell, jvm

I just recently started learning the Haskell language earlier this year and am working on a project that inputs a java class file (i.e FileName1.class) and dissect that file to print out the following:

- name of the class deﬁned by the class ﬁle
- the number of methods of the class, their names and types

I did some research and found that this is possible by using a JVM but am a little lost in the process, anyone have any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write a parser for the Java class format.

Luckily there are already [libraries to do that.](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-java-classfile)

Parse the file, inpsect the AST generated, print the required information.

Answer (score 1):

Give [parsec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/daan/download/parsec/parsec.html) a try.

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsec

This is an incredibly good tutorial on how to get started: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Parsing_expressions_and_statements

And also from Real World Haskell: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html

Parsec even contains a default Java language definition.
http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.0/doc/html/src/Text-Parsec-Language.html#javaStyle

Also, when inspecting your AST, you might want to use the Reader monad to keep your type signatures from getting too polluted.

Comment: Parsec will be fine if you want to parse the Java source code. If you're really talking about Java `*.class` files (i.e., compiled binary data) then Parsec won't help you at all.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: well, understanding Parsec should at least be a good starting point for moving on to something like [`attoparsec`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.10.4.0).